# Cannot modify registry keys for WebBrowser printing

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, registry, webbrowser-control

I have the following code to print a document from the WebBrowser without the header and footer:

```
string keyName = @"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\PageSetup";
            using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(keyName, true))
            {
                if (key != null)
                {
                    string old_footer = key.GetValue("footer").ToString();
                    string old_header = key.GetValue("header").ToString();
                    key.SetValue("footer", "");
                    key.SetValue("header", "");
                    md_preview.ShowPrintDialog();
                    key.SetValue("footer", old_footer);
                    key.SetValue("header", old_header);
                }
            }
```

I am also `using Microsoft.Win32;`. However, when I try to print, I still get the header and footer on the printed page.

Comment: Does ShowPrintDialog() return only when printing is done? If the call does not block execution, the user sees the Print Dialog and the code restores the old values immediately after.

Comment: @AlexMazzariol how could I block the excecution? I am relatively new to WinForms and C#.

Comment: This is something you cannot do with the WebBrowser control. If you really need to show the print dialog before printing, you will not be able to get a notification of the print job having been queued, so you can reset the footer/header setting. You can use the Print() method instead, after which you can safely reset footer/header settings, but your user will not be able to choose a printer (or make any other changes to default print settings).